# Map EER diagram into a relational database schema

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm preparing for an exam tomorrow and have tried to solve previous exam questions for the course. I'm stuck and have problems translating EER into a relational schema. The problem is:

"Map the EER diagram given in Figure 1 into a relational database schema. Make sure all key attributes and foreign keys are displayed in the resulting database schema."

[figure 1 - image of EER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrWBT.jpg)

I tried to solve it, but to no avail. My solution to this is like the following:

- E1(**A1**)
- A10(**A1, A11, A12, A13**)
- R2E2(**A1, A2,** A20)
- R3E3(**A1, A2, A3,** A30)
- A51(**A4, A5,** A51)
- E6R6(**A1, A4, A5,** A6, A40, A60)
- E7(**A4, A5,** A7, A40)
- R8(**A4, A5, A8,** A80)
- E8(**A8**)

I strongly suspect its wrong and would like to know the correct step-to-step answer to this problem. I am trying to learn this conversion but this EER model is complex and I am struggling to map it correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Please give the EER reference you are using, there are many variations. Please tell us where you think you are certain & not & why.

Answer (score 0):

There are many variations on EER modeling, so I may not be interpreting the diagram in the same way you do. It would help if you included a reference for the EER notation you're using. I'll explain my interpretation so you can compare it with yours. I'll use a variation of your relational notation - instead of indicating primary keys in bold, I'll write PK; and UQ for unique. In addition, I'll indicate FK constraints as subsets, e.g. E2.A1 ⊆ E1.A1. Here we go:

E1 is a regular entity set with primary key A1 and a composite attribute A10 (composed of A11, A12 and A13). With composite attributes, we need only represent the component parts.

```
E1 (A1 PK, A11, A12, A13)
```

R2 is an identifying relationship for the weak entity set E2, which makes A2 its weak key, so E2 is identified by (A1, A2). We could map R2 and E2 separately:

```
R2 (A1 PK, A2 PK, A20)
E2 (A1 PK, A2 PK)
```

but since they have identical primary keys and neither can be recorded without the other (weak entity sets always participate fully in their relationships, since they can't be identified independently, and the weak entity set isn't optional in the relationship), we combine them into one relation:

```
R2E2 (A1 PK, A2 PK, A20)
R2E2.A1 ⊆ E1.A1
```

The EER notation here is a bit unclear. I would prefer to see weak entity sets connected to their identifying relationships by double (total) participation lines, and weak keys underlined with dashed lines. Assuming I'm interpreting it correctly, R3 is another identifying relationship for the weak entity set E3. By the same logic as above, we get:

```
R3E3 (A1 PK, A2 PK, A3 PK, A30)
R3E3.(A1,A2) ⊆ R2E2.(A1,A2)
```

E4 is a regular entity set:

```
E4 (A4 PK, A40)
```

E5 is a subtype of E4. I question the inclusion of PK attribute A5, since subtypes are a subset of their supertypes, and I would expect E5 to inherit A4 as its PK. Well, let's use A5 as given and we'll add an FK constraint to ensure A5 ⊆ A4.

```
E5 (A5 PK)
E5.A5 ⊆ E4.A4
```

The multivalued attributes A51 requires its own table to record each of the multiple values that may be assigned to an entity in A5:

```
E5A51 (A5 PK, A51 PK)
E5A51.A5 ⊆ E5.A5
```

E6 and E7 are disjoint subtypes of E4. E6 is simple enough:

```
E6 (A4 PK, A6)
```

but let's look at R6. It's a one-to-one relationship in which all E6 must participate. Technically, we only require

```
R6 (A1 UQ, A4 UQ, A80)
```

but we need to pick one of the attributes as the PK. A4 is the better choice since it allows us to combine the relations for R6 and E6 and thereby ensure total participation without another FK constraint:

```
R6E6 (E4 PK, A4 UQ, A6, A80)
R6E6.E4 ⊆ E4.A4
```

E7 and E8 are easy enough:

```
E7 (A4 PK, A7)
E7.A4 ⊆ E4.A4
E8 (A8 PK)
```

R8 is a many-to-many relationship determined by E7 and E8:

```
R8 (A4 PK, A8 PK, A80)
R8.A4 ⊆ E7.A4
R8.A8 ⊆ E8.A8
```

So, to summarize, we've got the following relations:

```
E1 (A1 PK, A11, A12, A13)
R2E2 (A1 PK, A2 PK, A20)
R3E3 (A1 PK, A2 PK, A3 PK, A30)
E4 (A4 PK, A40)
E5 (A5 PK)
E5A51 (A5 PK, A51 PK)
R6E6 (E4 PK, A4 UQ, A6, A80)
E7 (A4 PK, A7)
E8 (A8 PK)
R8 (A4 PK, A8 PK, A80)
```

And foreign key constraints:

```
R2E2.A1 ⊆ E1.A1
R3E3.(A1,A2) ⊆ R2E2.(A1,A2)
E5.A5 ⊆ E4.A4
E5A51.A5 ⊆ E5.A5
R6E6.E4 ⊆ E4.A4
E7.A4 ⊆ E4.A4
R8.A4 ⊆ E7.A4
R8.A8 ⊆ E8.A8
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to draw this as a table schema diagram. Hope this helps.